# Auth:sanctum middleware not protecting routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I installed Sanctum on my Laravel 9 site (one that I've been updating over the years over several versions), in order to try out adding token generation to my API.   I got the token generation working, it seems to work fine.

I tried to create a new route and protect it via the auth:sanctum middleware, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I can hit the route whether or not I pass a token in.   I also verified that I'm not logged in to the site using the standard login method.

In my api.php I have:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('tokens/validate', function () {
    return ['data' => 'token is valid'];
});
```

To test, I'm hitting the GET endpoint in Postman `/api/tokens/validate`, I get back the JSON with data 'token is valid'.

However if I hit the same route in a browser, it redirects me to the login page:  https://dev.arcane.city/api/tokens/validate

Looking back at the docs, I don't see any obvious steps I missed.

I double checked that my kernel.php has the api middleware groups set up:

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            EncryptCookies::class,
            AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
        'api' => [
            EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:60,1',
            SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

However, I noticed another question where it was suggested to remove the EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful, so I tried it with and without, and it made no difference.

Any tips about what might be happening?

---

My sanctum.php:

```
<?php

use Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum;

return [

    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1,arcane.city,dev.arcane.city',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),

    'guard' => ['web'],

    'expiration' => null,

    'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ],

];
```

My auth.php:

```
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    'driver' => 'eloquent',

    'model' => 'App\Models\User',

    'table' => 'users',

    'failed' => 'Unable to log in'
];
```

Comment: can you show the content of your config/sanctum.php?

Comment: whats on your `config/auth.php` and what was your old api authentication before you implemented sanctum?

Comment: Added those files.  I didn't remove any existing auth method here.  I'm still expecting users to auth web routes with their u/p and session, and api endpoints to use the token.   To be clear:  this app contains both a traditional laravel web site with auth and an API.

Comment: Still stumped on this one.  I went and updated to laravel 10 and the latest sanctum, but no change.  I started a new laravel 10 app, set up sanctum and a protected route and it proctects the route correctly (allows me in with the generated token).   Then I went through all the files in the new project vs the old one that might seem to have an impact, but I couldn't find anything that made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by comparing each config file in my project with the configs in a newly created Laravel 10 project until I found the issue.

TLDR:
I replaced my Authenticate middleware and Kernel.php  with the out of the box files from Laravel, and then progressively added back in what I needed to the Kernel.

Things are working as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and had the run the command below to get  it working again -

```
php artisan route:clear
```